# Will [or, can] Amazon cloudfront serve s3 images exactly like I get them now?

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Here's an example image from s3:
masterpiece.s3.amazonaws.com/6ffd948c-d73e-4db0-b0cc-e88ef74c1c36.jpg

So I'm wondering if moving to cloudfront will require me to edit all the image display code?

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask Amazon support as this really has nothing to do with code.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to replace or rewrite masterpiece.s3.amazonaws.com to your CloudFront distribution's DNS name.

Example:
masterpiece.s3.amazonaws.com -> d123.cloudfront.net

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html